# Convert query expression to dot notation

Tags: c#, linq

I want to convert these two query expression into dot notation

Q1

```
var x = from tbl in Person.Get(2, cat.Count)
        group cat[i] by i/10;
```

Q2

```
foreach(var a in x)
    string.Split("-", a);
```

How to do?

Comment: Q2 does not make a lot of sense. Should we assume that you want an `IEnumerable<string[]>` as the result?

Comment: I want to loop and print the result of the Split

Comment: Neither your Q1 and Q2 is correct, how can we merge them into a correct one?

Comment: @Bob: I think you will need to share a bit more detail to get good answers. What does `Person.Get` return (what do the objects look like)? What is `cat`?

Comment: cat is a string array and Person.Get() return IEnumerable<int>

Comment: For your future reference, section 7.16 of the C# specification contains detailed instructions on how to translate query syntax to "fluent" syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but please see if this produces correct results for you -

```
var catList = Person.Get(2, cat.Count);
catList.GroupBy(c => catList.Indexof(c)/10).Select(a => a.Split("-", a))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<string[]> result = (from tbl in Person.Get(2, cat.Count)
                        group cat[i] by i/10).Select(x=>x.Split('-'));
```